# Android+OpenCV: How to add a .cpp file to the project?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I'm developing an app with a friend. I've done the java part and him the cpp. Now I have to add his to mine but I don't know how to do it.

I have been looking some info. I have downladed the OpenCV 2.4.6 for Windows and I've added the library to the project, but I don't know the next step.

I have also checked the samples that they provide but I only see the java parts. I think I have a "concept error" maybe.

Where should the cpp file go inside the project? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does OpenCV have to do with building a project? What you need is a build tool, not a computer vision library.

Comment: I need to call and execute the cpp from the java, after taking a picture I want to process it with OpenCV. I'm reading this tutorial right now, I've juts found it, let see if it works: http://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory structure of your project should  like this

```
ProjectName |--> src
            |--> jni--|
            |         |--->Android.mk
            |         |--->Application.mk
            |         |--->main.cpp
            |         |--->newsourc.cpp
            |--> bin
            |--------
```

And you can add new source file in jni directory.

and edit your Android.mk to add new  source file to your project.

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)


include /home/PATH/OpenCV-2.4.2-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := name
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp newsourc.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Okey, I put main.cpp and then Android.mk (it is supossed that I should write what you told me in plain text and save it with that extension or is it a special way to create the file?). And what about Application.mk? Sorry for so many questions, but I've never programmed with C++ and I'm so confused.

Comment: It says that the includes inside the cpp are unresolved inclusions. The Android.mk that you told me seems perfect, but I don't know how to fix the other issue.

Comment: You can follow this link http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html  to setup opencv for android

Comment: That's the one I followed to install OpenCV and try the samples, and I use the search bar on the left but it doesn't find anything related with Application.mk nor Android.mk and in that page it doesn't appear. I'm now exploring the Samples code and trying to understand what should I write in my case...

Comment: They explain some in this, I'm still reading: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c